# Risk of invalidation of std::array data() in associative container?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::array<float,50>> foo;
...
auto pointerToArray = foo.at(3).data();
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781886/can-we-store-unordered-maptiterator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules). I have the following questions:

- 1) `pointerToArray` falls into which category when referring to the 
  invalidation rules, iterator or reference?
- 2) What are the risks that `pointerToArray` will get invalidated
  (assuming its paired key in `foo` is not erased)?
- 3) What, if any, difference is there in the answers to these
  questions between `unordered_map` and `map` ?

Unlike `vector`, `array` itself will not re-allocate and thus there is not a risk of it changing memory addresses on its own, but as it is inside a unordered/map, the plot thickens.

Update: Found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337612/3758484) that suggests there is no risk of invalidation in this case.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me that this goes the same as invalidating a pointer to a struct.

Comment: You should not think in terms of risk. Either it works or it doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand how [your second link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) does not answer your question.  A pointer to something is basically the same as a reference to something.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suppose part of the confusion is the standard's use of the word "reference" when I'm not using any C++ references in my example, hence my first question. Edit: I see you just changed your comment to answer the question in this reply.

Comment: @johnbakers Typically a reference is implemented as a pointer.  So you can interchange them in this context.

Comment: As stated in C++11 ISO §23.2.5.8: _Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements._. __Since you are calling `at` you are effectively accessing a reference to a mapped value so there are no risks.__ Don't be confused by the fact that you invoke `data()`, which returns a pointer, on the reference returned.

Comment: `at` returns a reference. Your `pointerToArray` isn't invalidated unless you remove index 3 yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided by the first link you provided, `pointerToArray` should **NOT** be invalidated by any subsequent changes made to the map, unless you were to erase the element itself from the map. The `std::array<float, 50>` object will be stored in the heap, and only the pointer (or possibly reference, depending on how `std::unordered_map` is implemented) to that object will be shuffled around within the map.